# Angular 6 target es5 IE Syntax error (arrow function)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ecmascript-5

Error in IE:
vendor.js (82613,35)

```
const emitsWrappingTags = (node) => {
  return !!node.kind;
};
```

Basically saying that IE don't know what arrow function is.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**polyfills.ts**

```
 /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
 /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
 import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
 /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
 import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
 /** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
 // Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
 import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
 import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "angular-highlightjs": "^0.6.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "highlightjs": "^9.8.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-highlight-js": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.10.2",
    "nl2br-pipe": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have seen multiple similar problems and solutions for them but non of them worked for my project. 
Typescript compiles to es6 regardless of above settings.I guess it has something to do with node packages but couldn't find which.

Comment: what about your `tsconfig.app.json` Perhaps the target is overwritten there?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I already added tsconfig.app.json to post.

Comment: Ahh, but it's coming from `vendor.js`, this means it comes from an already compiled 3rd party library. You should find out which one that is :)

Answer (score 2):

I found what caused problem. In my package.json i had :

```
 "highlightjs": "^9.8.0"
```

later i saw that in package-lock.json the version was 10.0.0

```
"highlight.js": {
      "version": "10.0.0",
```

as we can see in:
https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/VERSION_10_UPGRADE.md

> If your users have very old browsers, they may no longer be supported
>   (no more IE11, etc.). (We're using ES2015 code now.)

seems like its not so backward-compatible :D